# Regex pattern for Url in Fiddler

Tags: regex, fiddler, jsfiddle, regex-negation

I have to send different responses depending on the attribute values in the http request using Auto responder in fiddler by adding rules.

My Url's will be as folowed

1. http://example.com/path/page?type=b&edate=&dep=LGW  (value for 'dep' can be any thing from a list say [LGW,ABZ,EDI,GLA,BFS,BHX,BOH,BRS,CWL,DSA])
2. http://example.com/path/page?type=b&edate=22-04-2015&dep=LGW
3. http://example.com/path/page?type=b&edate=&dep=PMI  (for request 3 & 4 value for 'dep' can be anything other the values mentioned in the above list)
4. http://example.com/path/page?type=b&edate=22-04-2015&dep=PMI

In the request 1 & 3 'edate' will be empty and in request 2&4 will have a value for 'edate'.

I can able to write the regex for req 2 as

```
example.com?.+&edate=(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)&stay=0&dep=(LGW|ABZ|EDI|GLA|BFS|BHX|BOH|BRS|CWL|DSA)&.+
```

How to write the regex for request 3? I tried this:

```
example.com?.+&edate=(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)&stay=0&dep=!(LGW|ABZ|EDI|GLA|BFS|BHX|BOH|BRS|CWL|DSA)&.+
```

But it is validating only for the first item ie. LGW not validating the remaining.

correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.+` a couple of times which I would discourage you from doing because it's greedy and matches more than you think.

As for your question, matching 3 characters that **aren't** in a certain list would be done like so:

```
(?!LGW|ABZ|EDI|GLA|BFS|BHX|BOH|BRS|CWL|DSA).{3}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ILJT9UmNHU-rURtB)

Building on your original regex, I would do something like below here. But I had to change a bunch of things like the `&stay=0` part, the part up to the `?` in the url and the `&.+` at the end:

```
example.com[^?]*\?.+?&edate=(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*).*?&dep=((?!LGW|ABZ|EDI|GLA|BFS|BHX|BOH|BRS|CWL|DSA).{3})(?:&.+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0xXXeGaYhNV-wlz7)